# Are spoilers primary or secondary flight control surfaces?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, spoilers

The literature on primary and secondary flight controls is very contradictory.
My professor provided this image from which I infer that spoilers are used for primary flight control:
[image]

Also, [here](https://hursts.org.uk/airbus-technical/html/ar01s16.html) it says that spoilers qualify as primary flight control.

On the other hand, [Skybrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/flight-controls) lists spoilers as secondary flight controls.

What kind of flight controls are spoilers?

Comment: It really depends on the aircraft: on the first versions of the B-52 for example, spoilers were the primary and only control surface.

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a consistent definition for primary and secondary flight controls. It depends on the aircraft.

The [Airbus A310 FCOM](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A310-Flight_Controls.pdf) distinguishes between primary and secondary controls as follows:

> The **primary flight controls** ensure flight path control and include:
>
> - pitch control, using:
>
>   - the elevators, which are hinged to the Trimmable Horizontal Stabilizer (THS), and
>   - the Trimmable Horizontal Stabilizer (THS) which provides Pitch Trim.
> - roll control, using:
>
>   - 1 aileron per wing, and
>   - the 5 outboard spoilers (Nos. 3 to 7) on each upper wing surface, as roll spoilers.
> - yaw control, using a single rudder.
>
> [...] The **secondary flight controls** are lift and drag augmenting devices and
> includes:
>
> - flaps: there are one double slotted inboard flap and on single slotted outboard flap.
> - slats: there are three slat sections per wing (inner, center and outer). Associated with the slats a Kruger flap is located on the
>   leading edge of each wing, inboard of the inner slat section.
> - **spoilers**: there are 7 spoilers (Nos. 1 to 7) on each upper wing surface which are used as speed brakes, roll spoilers or ground
>   spoilers for lift dumping (all 7 surfaces).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Therefore, spoilers can be counted as primary controls, but only those which are actually used as roll spoilers (asymmetric deployment in the air).

As far as I could find, Airbus does not distinguish between primary and secondary controls in subsequent models.

---

The Boeing 747 FCOM (-400 and -8 models) defines the primary and secondary controls as follows:

> The **primary** flight controls are elevators, ailerons, and rudders. [...]
>
> **Secondary** flight controls include a moveable horizontal stabilizer, **spoilers**, and
> leading and trailing edge flaps.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Here, spoilers are clearly excluded from the primary flight controls. Other Boeing FCOMs I found define the primary flight controls in a similar way, but do not go into further details about secondary flight controls.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the aircraft.  For example:

- On a Learjet 45 airplane. There are spoilers that are mainly used in the air to slow down and/or descend.  However, when flaps are increased, those same spoilers become spoilerons and help the airplane roll.  There is even a roll disconnect feature that will disconnect the pilot side yoke to the aileron cables and solely use the spoilerons to roll the aircraft.

To summarize I would say this

- Spoilers are secondary flight controls.  In the air, the help the airplane slow down and/or descend.  On the ground, they are used to spoil lift and transfer the weight of the airplane to the wheels to aid in braking
- Spoilerons are primary flight controls.  They help the pilot maintain roll authority by either supplementing the ailerons or being the only way to roll the airplane.